# Computer to Electronics controller with programming API

Tags: microcontroller, programming

Basically, I need a way of connecting a computer to some simple electronics; some sort of microcontroller (I think that's the word!).

It doesn't need to be to complicated; all I'm doing is controlling LEDs and simple motors (7 motors, 20 LEDs maybe)(I only need ON/OFF).

The important bit is I'd like something with a programming API; something where I can write code in a programming language on the computer, run the code, and watch the lights and motors move and shine.

*I am looking just for the piece of kit, not how to use it, so that's why I think it should be here, not on SO.*

*(Sorry if my question is not very clear, I'm not really sure how to describe what I'm looking for)*

Comment: You think you can get away with it by using the word "microcontroller" :-), but it looks like a shopping question, and those are not allowed (even if Olin and I answered it as such). This question may be closed for that reason.

Comment: To me it is not clear whether you want to write code on your PC or on some other gadget? And when you say you want to control a motor, is that on/off, off/forward/reverse, or also variable power (PWM) or even controlled variable speed?

Answer (score 3):

Olin suggests National Instruments, and that would definitely be a good choice. But I've used boards from them (PCI), and they were anything but cheap, targeted at the industrial PC market.

[This](http://accesio.com/go.cgi?p=../usb/usb-dio-48.html) may be a cheaper alternative:

[image]

Still 195 dollar. Each of the 48I/Os can sink 64mA, which should be enough to activate the LEDs and most 12V relays. If they're DC motors you can also switch them with a transistor, but I would separate them from the board if possible: 10 motors can do bad things to the logic's power supply.

Answer (score 3):

On your profile (kudos for filling it in) I don't see any electronics experience, and I don't know if you're interested in it. If you are a good way to start is [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Hardware). It won't reveal you all the secrets of microcontroller programming, but then you don't need all that to get started either, and that can be a plus.

A basic Arduino board will let you communicate with the PC via a virtual COM port, and a UART on the Arduino. Very easy to activate those outputs. You won't have 30 I/Os right away, but a couple of [TPIC6C595](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6c595.pdf)s will get you all the outputs you need.

Answer (score 2):

30 motors is a lot.  In general it sounds like you want basic digital I/O capability added to your general purpose computer.  Yes, this can be easily done with a microcontroller if you know how to do it.  You obviously don't and apparently don't have much interest in the journey, so I recommend you just get some off the shelf digital I/O modules.

My first suspect for such things would be National Instruments, but I'm sure various others make these things too.  These would generally plug into the USB and come with a library so you can controll everything via their subroutines on your PC.

Comment: Olin, the cheapest NI board capable of 30 I/Os was [this one](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/207096), but it's 1049 euros. Did you have a cheaper one in mind?

Comment: I haven't looked.  Like I said, 30 outputs is a lot.  I used a small USB module from them once that was only like $150.  Two or even three of them should have 30 outputs.

Comment: The thing with NI is that you pay for that 16-bit resolution AD/DA you always get, even if it's not required like here.

Comment: @stevenvh: Like I said, NI is only what came to mind as the first suspect.  I'm not specifically recommending their stuff, only passing on the information that they exist and make products in this space.

Comment: Cheaper USB stuff here http://www.phidgets.com/ or http://www.mccdaq.com

Comment: OP is 15, may not have the wallet for this stuff.